# Why was NOP assigned to 0x90 in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, machine-code, no-op

Why was `nop` assigned to `0x90` on intel x86 assembly?

Intuitively I would expect that `0x00` would map to `nop` (which is also `xchg eax, eax` at intel x86) as it is the case for `ARM A32` and some other architectures.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

0x00000000 is not actually NOP on ARM A32 though it behaves like one; it's actually `andeq r0, r0, r0` whereas a real NOP is `0xe1a00000` (mov r0, r0).  It's a rather bad idea to have the NUL byte be a NOP because that makes every empty memory region a free NOP slide, greatly increasing the risk for attacks.  Modern architectures generally try to make all zeroes be a break instruction or similar to avoid this attack vector.  For example, ARM A64 makes `0x00000000` a permanently undefined instruction `udf 0`.

`0x90` is actually just one instruction of the `0x90 + r` opcode family which stands for `xchg r32, eax`.  `eax` is register 0, so `0x90` stands for `xchg eax, eax` which is a NOP.  In long mode, `0x90` is special cased  not to zero out the high 32 bit of `rax` to keep its function as a single byte NOP.

Comment: The good old [6502 viewed 0x00 as the BRK instruction](https://www.masswerk.at/6502/6502_instruction_set.html). So it is not that recent.